# how to add more words in the Toxicity classifier

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

is there a way i can add more words to the 
toxicity classifier ?

this is what i am using at the moment just a basic script
from the example given in the github page

```
// The minimum prediction confidence.
const threshold = 0.9;

// Load the model. Users optionally pass in a threshold and an array of
// labels to include.
toxicity.load(threshold).then(model => {
  const sentences = ['you suck'];

  model.classify(sentences).then(predictions => {
    // `predictions` is an array of objects, one for each prediction head,
    // that contains the raw probabilities for each input along with the
    // final prediction in `match` (either `true` or `false`).
    // If neither prediction exceeds the threshold, `match` is `null`.

    console.log(predictions);
    /*
    prints:
    {
      "label": "identity_attack",
      "results": [{
        "probabilities": [0.9659664034843445, 0.03403361141681671],
        "match": false
      }]
    },
    {
      "label": "insult",
      "results": [{
        "probabilities": [0.08124706149101257, 0.9187529683113098],
        "match": true
      }]
    },
    ...
     */
  });
});
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity

Answer (score 1):

You can add more words in the array sentences for the predictions:

```
const sentences = ['you suck', 'add whatever you want'];
```

However, you cannot change the labels of the model. You can only do so during the training of the model. The toxicity model was trained using python before being ported to js. So you can only change the labels by retraining the python model.